# Walrus Operator in match statement results in invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

I don't understand why the following python 3.10+ code is invalid syntax:

```py
match prop.type:
    case ns.Instance(content := ns.Class(name)) if name is not None:
        continue
```

To me, this matches the [walrus patterns](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#walrus-patterns) patten documented there. What's wrong? I get the following error:

```
case ns.Instance(content := ns.Class(name)) if name is not None:
                             ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Further, `pylace` shows me the following errors (in the editor):

```
case ns.Instance(content := ns.Class(name)) if name is not None:
                ^
"(" was not closed
```

And further

```
case ns.Instance(content := ns.Class(name)) if name is not None:
                                                               ^
Expected ":"
```

Not sure to what extend this is relevant, but the definition of `Instance` is:

```py
@dataclass
class Instance(Type):
    content: Type
```

Comment: I didn't realise that the walrus operator could be used as a parameter. However, you don't seem to need `content` as a variable. Can you remove it and just have `ns.Class(name)` as the parameter?

Comment: I do in my original code, this is shortened for clarity :) Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question to give us motivation keep the walrus operator.

Comment: If you need motivation to keep it, I don't think this question is for you :) But thanks for the consideration!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Walrus patterns don't exist. You're looking at the superseded PEP for the original pattern matching proposal. The syntax there isn't quite what was finally implemented.

You should look at [PEP 634](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/), particularly [`as` patterns](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#as-patterns), which replaced walrus patterns:

```
case ns.Instance(ns.Class(name) as content) if name is not None:
```

Comment: Ah, misleading documentation. Thank you!